# How to let user upload CSV to MongoDB from any directory

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb

I've been trying to do a simple upload function that let's the user choose a CSV file from his PC and upload it into my Mongo DB. I am currently using Python, Pymongo and Pandas to do it and it works, but only with my "local" adress *(C:\Users\joao.soeiro\Downloads)* as it shows on the code.

I'd like to know how I could make this string "dynamic" so it reads and uploads files from anywhere, not only my computer. I know it must be a silly question but im really a begginer here...

Thought about creating some temporary directory using tempfile() module but idk how I'd put it to work in my code, which is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient


client =  MongoClient("mongodb+srv://xxx:xxx@bycardb.lrp4p.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
print('connected')
db = client['dbycar']
collection = db['users']


data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\joao.soeiro\Downloads\csteste4.csv')
data.reset_index(inplace=True)
data_dict = data.to_dict("records")
collection.insert_many(data_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from IPython.display import display
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient


#conecting db
client =  MongoClient("mongodb+srv://xxxx:xxxx@bycardb.lrp4p.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
print('conectado com o banco')
db = client['dbycar']
collection = db['usuarios']

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
print(file_path)

data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
data.reset_index(inplace=True)
data_dict = data.to_dict("records")
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
display(df)
collection.insert_many(data_dict)
print('uploaded')
```